# Mysql: Change date format

Tags: mysql

I want to change the date format in mm/yyyy. My query like that.

```
select shipwynum,
        IF (s.adjdeldat != '',  s.adjdeldat,s.condeldat) as -- adjdeldat and condeldat are date type
        deliverydate,
FROM ship
Result of that query come in yyyymmdd fromat but i want result in mm/yyyy format.
```

I use DATE_FORMAT like that

```
DATE_FORMAT(s.adjdeldat,'%m/%Y')
DATE_FORMAT(s.condeldat,'%m/%Y')
```

but it does not work properly.

Comment: What is the data type of column `adjdeldat`? Can you post result of `show variable 'date_format'`?

Comment: Data type is varchar for adjdeldat and condeldat and it save data in yyyymmdd or yyyymm

Comment: You mean some data is in `20140415` format and some in `201404` format?

Comment: Yes, and i want that data in 04/2014 format

Comment: Required format is OK. My question is that whether the data is stored in a consistent pattern of `yyyymmdd` format or not in both of the columns?

Comment: yes, it store data in both yyyymmdd and yyyymm format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***From the comments and post***:

> *Data type is `varchar` for `adjdeldat` and `condeldat` and it save data in* ***`yyyymmdd`*** *or* ***`yyyymm`***
>
> *I want to change the date format in* ***`mm/yyyy`***
>
> *You mean some data is in* ***`20140415`*** *format and some in* ***`201404`*** *format?*
>
> *Yes, and i want that data in* ***`04/2014`*** *format*

**Change your query as below**:

```
select 
  shipwynum,
  if( s.adjdeldat != '',  
      date_format( str_to_date( s.adjdeldat, '%Y%m%d' ), '%m/%Y' ),
      date_format( str_to_date( s.condeldat, '%Y%m%d' ), '%m/%Y' ) 
  ) deliverydate,
from ship
```

Even if some the date values miss `dd` part, MySQL silently replaces them with `00` when converted from `str_to_date`.

**Example**:

```
select 
  @dt:=str_to_date( '201404', '%Y%m%d' ) dt, 
  date_format( @dt, '%m/%Y' ) df;
```

**Result**:

```
+------------+---------+
| dt         | df      |
+------------+---------+
| 2014-04-00 | 04/2014 |
+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It give me syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%Y' ), date_format( str_to_date( s.condeldat, '%Y%m%d` ), '%m%Y' ))) as 
      ' at line 2

Comment: Ok. I accidentally typed a back tick. Updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

*try this:*

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
```

***http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp***

*your code as like:*

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M %Y');

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.date, '%M/%Y') FROM t1 AS a;
```

***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format***

***sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a68f/2***